# Getting binary column from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to import a column from a SQL Server database using C#.

When I use SQL Server Enterprise, it is shown as `<binary>` and when I run query on the SQL Server, it returns the right binary values.

However, when I try coding with C# like so:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=portable;Database=data;Integrated Security=true;");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT bnry FROM RawData", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader. //I do not know what to put here
}

reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

When I put `reader.GetSqlBinary(0));`, I only get many `SqlBinary<4096>`s as output.

When I look at SQL Server Query Analyzer, when I try the same command, it gets me `0x0000..` type of code.

What should I put after reader. or is there another method of getting this data from the database?

Comment: So using Query Analyzer and Enterprise (Manager, presumably) - does this mean you're using SQL Server **2000** ? That would be very relevant info (since that version is so ancient, most of today's approaches in SQL Server won't work with such a version)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting back an array of bytes, so use :

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])reader[0];
```

What you do with them from there depends on what the bytes represent.

Comment: When I do `byte[] bytes = (byte[])reader[0]; Console.WriteLine(bytes)` it still gives me a lot of `System.Byte[]` s...

Comment: Right, that's what should happen.  What are the bytes supposed to be?  If it's an image, you can convert it to an image using a `MemoryStream` object and the `Image.FromMemoryStream()` method or just save it to disk by `File.WriteAllBytes(byteArray)`.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do this is with a stream so that you properly dispose of the stream (probably coming via a socket connection) when finished. So I would use [GetStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using(Stream stream = reader[0].GetStream())
{
  //do your work on the stream here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this table

```
create table dbo.bin_test
(
  c1 binary(8)    not null ,
  c2 binary(8)        null ,
  c3 varbinary(8) not null ,
  c4 varbinary(8)     null ,
)
insert dbo.bin_test values ( 0x1234     , null       , 0x1234     , null       )
insert dbo.bin_test values ( 0x012345678 , 0x12345678 , 0x12345678 , 0x12345678 )
```

This code (IF you're going to use `SQLBinary`)

```
string connectString = "Server=localhost;Database=sandbox;Trusted_Connection=True;" ;
using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectString) )
using ( SqlCommand    cmd        = connection.CreateCommand() )
{

  cmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.bin_test" ;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text ;

  connection.Open() ;
  using ( SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() )
  {
    int row = 0 ;
    while ( reader.Read() )
    {
      for ( int col = 0 ; col < reader.FieldCount ; ++col )
      {
        Console.Write( "row{0,2}, col{1,2}: " , row , col ) ;
        SqlBinary octets = reader.GetSqlBinary(col) ;
        if ( octets.IsNull )
        {
          Console.WriteLine( "{null}");
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine( "length={0:##0}, {{ {1} }}" , octets.Length , string.Join( " , " , octets.Value.Select(x => string.Format("0x{0:X2}",x)))) ;
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine() ;
      ++row ;
    }
  }
  connection.Close() ;
}
```

should produce:

```
row 0, col 0: length=8, { 0x12 , 0x34 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 }
row 0, col 1: {null}
row 0, col 2: length=2, { 0x12 , 0x34 }
row 0, col 3: {null}

row 1, col 0: length=8, { 0x00 , 0x12 , 0x34 , 0x56 , 0x78 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 }
row 1, col 1: length=8, { 0x12 , 0x34 , 0x56 , 0x78 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 }
row 1, col 2: length=4, { 0x12 , 0x34 , 0x56 , 0x78 }
row 1, col 3: length=4, { 0x12 , 0x34 , 0x56 , 0x78 }
```

But as noted, it's probably cleaner to simply do this:

```
byte[] octets = reader[0] as byte[] ;
if ( octets == null )
{
  Console.WriteLine( "{null}");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine( "length={0:##0}, {{ {1} }}" , octets.Length , string.Join( " , " , octets.Select(x => string.Format("0x{0:X2}",x)))) ;
}
```

And get the same result.

Comment: They both give me errors of `The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, String[])' has some invalid arguments` and `Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'`

Comment: What version of the CLR (.Net runtime) are you using? `String.Join()` got overloads that take `IEnumerable<string>` with .Net 4.0. If you're using .Net 2.0/3.5 you'll need to append `.ToArray()` to `octets.Select(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should access data from `SqlDataReader` indexer ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

So it would look like this:

```
//..
Console.WriteLine((byte[])reader["bnry"]); 
//..
```

**UPDATE:**

I guess I finally got where is your problem. We are not on the same page here. I will try to be as simple as possible.

For start you need to understand that **all the information** in computers are stored in memory as a bunch of bytes. It is quite cumbersome to work directly with bytes in memory, so different data types were introduced (`int`, `string`, `Image`, etc) to ease programmers life. Most objects in .NET still can be converted to their internal representation as a byte array in one or other way. During this conversion you loose the information about what byte array contains - it can easily be `Image`, `string` or even `int` array. **To get back from binary representation, you need to know what byte array contains.**

In your example you are trying to write out byte array directly. As output always needs to be text, byte array somehow needs to be converted to `string`. This is done by calling `.ToString()` function on byte array. Unfortunately for you, default implementation of `.ToString()` for complex objects just returns type name. That's where all those `System.Byte[]` and `SqlBinary<4096>` lines are coming from.

To get over this issue, before displaying result you need to convert byte array to necessary type. It seems that in your case byte array contains some textual information, so I guess you need to convert byte array to `string`. To do that, you need to know encoding (way how `string` is stored in memory) of the text.

Basically, your code should look like this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=portable;Database=data;Integrated Security=true;");
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT bnry FROM RawData", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    var valueAsArray = (byte[])reader["bnry"];

    //as there are different encodings possible, you need to find encoding what works for you
    var valueAsStringDefault = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(valueAsArray);
    Console.WriteLine(valueAsStringDefault);

    //...or...
    var valueAsStringUTF8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(valueAsArray);
    Console.WriteLine(valueAsStringUTF8);

    //...or...
    var valueAsStringUTF7 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetString(valueAsArray);
    Console.WriteLine(valueAsStringUTF7);

    //...or any other encoding. Most of them you can find in System.Text.Encoding namespace...
}

reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: It gives me an error saying "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'Items' and no extension method 'Items' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' could be found"

Comment: There was a typo - instead of `Items` it should say `Item`. Fixed that.

Comment: Sorry, misread documentation. It is not property, but indexer for `SqlDataReader` itself. Edited once more. This time I tried it myself and it works.

Comment: There are no errors with it when I put it as you wrote but then it gives me `System.byte[]` s which was the original problem I was having..